# Print multiple lines as single line with string separator

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file where each line contains a string, like this:

```
Jane
Sally
John
Jim
```

I would like to reformat my file so that each line is combined into a single line with a new string separating each original string, like this:

```
JaneNNNNNSallyNNNNNJohnNNNNNJim
```

I can combine my multiline format into single line format using either cat or paste, like so:

```
cat file.txt | tr -s '\n' 'NNNNN'
paste -sd 'NNNNN' file.txt
```

But these include only a single 'N' as padding between strings, like this:

```
JaneNSallyNJohnNJim
```

How can I pad with a multicharacter string? Perhaps sed would be more efficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
awk '$1=$1' OFS='NNNNN' RS='' file
```

Update with [Ed's note below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61349417/print-multiple-lines-as-single-line-with-string-separator/61349506#comment108530378_61349506):

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS='NNNNN' RS='' file
```

Output:

```
JaneNNNNNSallyNNNNNJohnNNNNNJim
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: That'd behave the same way in any awk, not just GNU. It'd fail if the first line was a zero though - always use `{$1=$1}1` unless you **need** `$1=$1` alone to test the result of the assignment to decide whether or not to print. The way it'd behave given a blank line may or may not be desirable but we don't have any input/output like that to compare to.

Comment: @EdMorton: I usually only test it with GNU awk. Thanks for the advice on `$1=$1`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: You're welcome. It'd also fail if there were blanks among the text in a line if the requirement is to join lines with `NNNNN` rather than join "words". If you just set `FS='\n'` it'll solve both this and, coincidentally, the `$1=$1` problem.

Comment: Thanks for the awk example and resource @Cyrus! Gets me exactly what I want.

Comment: Thanks @Ed Morton!

Comment: This will fail if you have more than 1 word in a line: it will even split the words with the delimiter.

Answer (score 6):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box and only reading one line at a time into memory (as opposed to, say, the whole file):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", ors, $0; ors="NNNNN"} END{print ""}' file
JaneNNNNNSallyNNNNNJohnNNNNNJim
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/NNNNN/g' file
```

Slurp the file into memory and replace each newline by `NNNNN`.

Of course you could use:

```
paste -s file | sed 's/\t/NNNNN/g'
```

Or:

```
printf "%sNNNNNN" $(<file) | sed 's/NNNNN$/\n/'
```

N.B. The last solution will not work with multiple words on a line.

Comment: @Quasímodo most likely but I can only say for sure for the tools at my disposal.

Comment: @Quasímodo No. But `sed -e ':a' -e 'N;$!ba' -e 's/\n/NNNNN/g' file` would; `:` and `b` commands can't be followed by a semicolon. If I'm not mistaken this restriction will be removed from the standard soon though